# sdist/bdist_wheel not including pyc in Linux but is included in Windows

Tags: python, linux, setuptools, python-wheel, sdist

I am trying to create a Python distribution where I have to include both the source and the compiled binary. (Yes, I read arguments against/for adding `.pyc`, but my use case requires the `.pyc` to be added). Running my steps in Windows, both the source and compiled binaries are added in the output file (I used both `sdist` and `bdist_wheel`).

Say I have the following structure:

```
root
+--folderA
   +--alpha
   +--beta
   +--__init__.py
+--folderB
```

`folderA` contains source codes while `folderB` contains other files within its subdirectories.

Steps done:

1. Modules are compiled using `compileall`
2. Sources in `alpha` are removed. Sources in `beta` are kept.
3. Run `python setup.py sdist|bdist_wheel`

I used `find_packages()` in setup.py to detect the modules. Modules in `alpha` are not detected while those in `beta` are found.

In the results `.tgz` and `.whl` files in Windows, all the needed files are there. All is good.

However, when the same procedure is done in Linux (Ubuntu to be specific), only the modules in `beta` are added and some modules in `folderB` but *not other files of different type and the module `alpha`*. `sdist` will give only the source while `bdist` and `bdist_wheel` will give the `.pyc`s only. I understand that `sdist` is for distributing source files while `bdist` is for binary files.

My question is *why is the behavior different in Windows* and is it possible to produce the same output in Linux (source and `.pyc` along with other files)?

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include files in sdist add them to [MANIFEST.in](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute):

```
global-include *.py *.pyc
```

Including `*.pyc` into wheels works for me on Linux without any special configuration, I just do

```
python setup.py build
python -m compileall build
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

PS. If you're trying to hide sources from people — you're on the wrong track. `*.pyc` files can be decompiled. There is a [disassembler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) in standard library and there are many [decompilers and uncompilers](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=Python+bytecode+decompiler) out there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. As for the hiding source, we do have our reasons but we do not think we will have to do this for long :).

Comment: Sorry are the four commands, supposed to be FOUR different ways to generate the package?

Comment: All right, I seem to get this one: `build`, `compile`, and `sdist|bdist_wheel` should be executed in sequence.

Comment: Yep, exactly. PS. There are more ways to generate packages — `sdist` for source distribution, `bdist_egg` and `bdist_wheel` for "eggs" and "wheels", `bdist_deb` and `bdist_rpm`…

Comment: How would I specifically exclude all *.py files and only distribute the *.pyc files? Is the MANIFEST.in taken into consideration for bdist_wheel, or just sdist?

Comment: `MANIFEST.in` is only for `sdist`.